# regex that returns matches of a range in length and containing one of several words in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I tried the following regex in Ruby:

```
"the foodogand the catlada are mouseing".scan(/\b(?=\w{6,12}\b)\w{0,9}(cat|dog|mouse)\w*/)
```

but instead of it returning

```
["foodogand", "catlada", "mouseing"]
```

I'm getting

```
[["dog"],["cat]]  # the results are also in arrays
```

What's wrong here?
the results are also in arrays, I could flatten this but is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Do you mean `mous` instead of `mouse` in your regex? `mouse` won't match `mousing`.

Comment: debuggex says it should match: http://www.debuggex.com/r/IQNZe0s7PJjmX47x/0

Comment: sorry thanks corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `?:` for the last group:

```
"the foodogand the catlada are mouseing".scan(/\b(?=\w{6,12}\b)\w{0,9}(?:cat|dog|mouse)\w*/)
#=> ["foodogand", "catlada", "mouseing"]
```

From the docs:

> If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

The `?:` makes the group non-capturing, avoiding a nested array.

Comment: @user1297102 `?:` means - A non-capturing group i believe

Comment: so it voids the parenthesis around cat|dog|mouse?

Comment: It acts as a group (you can apply operators to the group), but it doesn't capture anything and doesn't create backreferences.

Answer (score 1):

I would just clean that up a bit by moving the second `\b` to the end and replacing `\w{0,9}` with `\w*` (the lookahead takes care of the length)

```
"the foodogand the catlada are mouseing".scan /\b(?=\w{6,12})\w*(?:cat|dog|mouse)\w*\b/
#=> ["foodogand", "catlada", "mouseing"]
```